# Why does fopen return errno 21 ("is a directory") when I open a file

Tags: c++, directory, fopen

So I am trying to open a file with fopen which usually works fine but for one file it thinks that I hand it a directory, not a file.

This is my call:

```
fopen("/data/data/something/file.typ", "wb");
```

Does anyone know why fopen could think that that it is trying to open a directory? Could the error number/description be misleading?

Comment: Are you on a mac? Sometimes, things that look like files are actually directories.

Comment: I'm on android actually. and Ii have successfully opened files with this  call before...

Comment: I have created this file manually before so it is definitely a file.

Comment: Do you check that the `fopen` call actually failes before checking `errno`? If a function succeeds the state of `errno` is undefined.

Comment: Interesting! Ill try that. I manually set errno to 0 before the call to check if it failed.

Comment: No that's not what you should do. You should only check `errno` if `fopen` returns `NULL`. Like I said before, the state of `errno` after a successful function call is **undefined**, it doesn't have to keep whatever value you set it to before the call.

Comment: just checked, it returns NULL :(

Comment: Thank you for your explanation Joachim. I have changed all my functions with fopen to check accordingly. The result is unfortunately the same. fopen returns NULL and errno is 21

Comment: Is there anything else that could set errno to 21?

Comment: have you found what was causing that error 21? i am having the same issue and have no sense in my case also.